# Meteor Dev Tools Auditor is marking collections as insecure

Tags: google-chrome, security, meteor

I use [Meteor Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-devtools/ippapidnnboiophakmmhkdlchoccbgje?hl=en) plugin in Chrome, and I’ve noticed a cool new feature, that is worrying me about the way I've coded my app. 
The audit collection tool is telling me that some of my collections are insecure.

**I am still using Meteor 1.2 with Blaze**

1.
One of them is `meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions`

1.1. should I worry about this one?

1.2. How do I protect it? 
`Insert`, `Update` and `Remove` are marked as insecure.

2.
Then I have a `cycles` collection, which has marked as insecure: `update` and `remove`
This collection is updated on the database now and then but not supposed to be accessed from the frontend, and is not meant to be related to any client interaction.

For this collection I have these allow/deny rules in a common folder (both client and server)
I've tried applying these rules only on the server side, but I didn't see a difference on the audit results.

2.1. Should these rules be only on the server side?

```
Cycles.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return false;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return false;
    },
    update: function () {
        return false;
    }
});
Cycles.deny({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    }
});
```

2.2. How do I protect this collection?

3.
And then, I also have another collection with an insecure check which is `users`, where `remove` is marked as insecure.
On this webapp I don't make any use of users, there is no login, etc.
I might want to implement this in the future, though.

3.1 Should I worry about this collection being insecure, since I don't use it at all?

3.2 How do I protect this collection?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to allow or deny. Just remove the insecure package from the meteor app.
Then you can use publish/subscribe and methods for data insert, update and delete.

Remove this please fo code from app:

```
Cycles.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return false;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return false;
    },
    update: function () {
        return false;
    }
});
Cycles.deny({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    }
});
```

> For 1.1

This happens while the user is logging. 
Basically, issue is not with this but with the login method. 
see wait time: https://ui.kadira.io/pt/2fbbd026-6302-4a12-add4-355c0480f81d

*why login method slow?*

This happens when everytime, your app gets reconnected. So, after the sucessful login, it will re-run all the publications again. That's why you saw such a delay to login hence this publication.

There is no such remedy for this and but this is kind fine unless your app is having a lot of througput/subRate to this method/publication.

For 3.1 : 
You do not have to worry about inscure anymore after removing allow/deny and insecure package. But make sure, you write secure methods.

Comment: I don't have the insecure package.

Comment: and all the insertions and updates are within methods

Comment: after removing the allow/deny rules, the Cycles collection is not marked as insecure anymore

Comment: Cool. Let me know if need something else from me.

Comment: Any comments on 1.1 and 3.1?

Comment: Update my answer please check.

Comment: regarding 1.1, I don't understand what you're talking about, probably because your link is not working (blank page)

Comment: Do you know how to use kadira package for check response dealy ?

Comment: no, and I still don't know what delay you are talking about

Comment: Please check may be you find this helpful : https://bulletproofmeteor.com/basics/wait-time-and-unblocking